How to get device screen time and app usage time
I am trying to get device screen time and screen time for particular apps, like the Digital Wellbeing stats.
private void collectUsageData() {
        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Set the start time to 24 hours ago
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        // Set the end time to the current time
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        UsageEvents usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(startTime, endTime);

        UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
        String currentPackage = null;
        long startForegroundTime = 0;

        while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
            usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);

            if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
                currentPackage = event.getPackageName();
                startForegroundTime = event.getTimeStamp();
            } else if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND) {
                if (currentPackage != null && startForegroundTime > 0) {
                    long usageTime = event.getTimeStamp() - startForegroundTime;
                    totalAppUsage += usageTime;
                    if (currentPackage.equals("com.instagram.android")) {
                        instagramUsage += usageTime;
                    } else if (currentPackage.equals("com.android.youtube")) {
                        youtubeUsage += usageTime;
                    }
                    currentPackage = null;
                    startForegroundTime = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        long totalScreenOnTime = 0;
        String totalTimeFormattedNum = formatTime(totalScreenOnTime);
        totalTime.setText(totalTimeFormattedNum);

        long wastedTimeNum = instagramUsage + youtubeUsage;
        String wastedTimeFormatted = formatTime(wastedTimeNum);
        wastedTime.setText(wastedTimeFormatted);
    }

My collected data is a lot different from Digitial Wellbeing. What mistake I am making here?
